# graphviz on Mac (monterrey 12.7.2)

Tags: python, macos, graphviz

I installed graphviz after installing Macports, to be able to use it on VS code.
I started programming on Windows, but since I got this machine, I will keep this one for programming purposes.

The thing is VS code does not import graphviz

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'`

I checked that graphviz was installed, and it is.

`guillermo@Guillermos-MacBook-Air ~ % dot -V    dot - graphviz version 9.0.0 (20230911.1827) guillermo@Guillermos-MacBook-Air ~ % which dot /opt/local/bin/dot`

I remember on windows I had to add the environment variable path, I saw a couple of posts about it for mac, but I cant make it work

any help is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: easy but hacky way: `import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/local/bin/dot")`

Comment: The Graphviz *application*, and the Python *module* for talking to Graphviz, are two entirely separate pieces of software - written by different people, installed in different places.  You currently only have the first piece installed.

Answer (score -1):

I just got this resolved myself.
I used chat gpt to add the path, it gave me step by step all the line codes to add in the terminal, and later I had to install the graphviz again, but instead of using sudo port install graphviz (which I used before), I used pip install graphviz and it worked.

It did not make much sense, because macports even tells you to use sudo port install graphviz. It is probably the same, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Do you understand that `port` and `pip` install two separate packages? The thing installed by `port` is *used* by the thing installed by `pip`.

Comment: they are, but the instructions are unclear from both sites (mac ports and graphviz). anyways chat gpt was my savior